# RegEx to get filename in quotes

Tags: java, regex

I have a filename (or basically a string, since it doesnt need to have an extension, can have spaces though) that is encapsulated by quotes in a string of the following format:

```
attachment; filename="Some filename.ext"
```

So basically my approach (java) was to take a `Matcher` with a `Pattern`:

```
Matcher mat = Pattern.compile("attachment; filename=\"([\\w\\.]+)\"").matcher(filename);
```

But `myMatcher.find()` returns `False`

Where does the RegEx go wrong?

Comment: What do you want to find in that string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\\w` does not match spaces. Also, you don't need to (but may) escape the `.` inside character classes. If you just want to allow spaces, add them to the character class:

```
"attachment; filename=\"([\\w. ]+)\""
```

If there maybe more characters than spaces, letters, digits, periods and underscores, you might want to use a negative character class instead, that just takes in everything until the next quote:

```
"attachment; filename=\"([^\"]+)\""
```